# How can I implement the following function in r programming?

Tags: r, function, logarithm, taylor-series

Hello I'm trying to implement the function of maclaurin series shown in the attached image below in r programming. I'm new to r programming can someone tell me how to fix the code i have. Thanks!!

```
macseries <- log(1+x)
macseries = sum((-1^n+1)x^n/n)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Note that in R, both `<-` and `=` assign values, so your second `macseries` overwrites your first.

Comment: Try `macseries <- function(x) log(1+x)` etc...

Comment: `f <- \(x,n=100000) sum((-1)^((1:n)+1)*x^(1:n)/(1:n))`, then do `f(1)`
Of course, taylor series for logarithms will not converge beyond 2. (beyond 1 for ln(1 + x))

Comment: Note that `-1^n+1` isn't the same thing as `(-1)^(n+1)`. Parentheses and order of operation matters. Also -- you need to use `*` rather than juxtaposition to multiply two things.

Comment: How can i  write the first 3 terms of this series

Comment: I think `(-1)^(1:3+1) * x^(1:3)/3`